# Securing SSH for cross site access

Tags: ssh, port

We have 2 servers, one each located at different geographical locations where we are considering using an rsync script to keep certain folders in sync.  Our setup disables root login and password logins and relies on keyfiles.

We run SSH on port 22X (just to minimize the login attempts, not as a way of security through obscurity).

If we setup port forwarding so that port XYZ forwards to 22X, and have disabled password logins, what other measures should we take to prevent any malicious activity occurring because of the open port?

My thinking is that as long as we keep our keys secure, then there should not be an issue.  have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding exclusively the security on the `sshd` service, these are some extra measures you could implement, in no particular order:

1. If this `sshd` daemon is expected to be used only between this two peers, an `iptables` rule restricting access to port 22X based on source IP address.
2. A `tcpwappers` ACL.
3. `fail2ban` can add rules dynamically to both `iptables` and `/etc/hosts.allow` to mitigate brute-force attacks.
4. Configure [port-knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking). [`fwknop`](http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/) is available in some distributions.
5. Depending on the version and the distribution of `openssh` you use,  you can setup two-factor authentication, using `kerberos` for example.
6. Do you already use a mandatory access control KSM (SELinux, apparmor, ...)?
7. Renew your keys regularly.
8. Take a look at the [monkeysphere](http://web.monkeysphere.info/) project. They provide a nifty way to add GPG validation to authorized keys.

Comment: I am familiar with fail2ban, so that's a good one just to stop repeat offenders, and we have a static public IP, so implementing an iptables rule would just about do it. I will look into the other ones as well.